# Routes controller overriding

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am developing a website using the MVC pattern with the CodeIgniter framework.

I have 2 controllers:

## Site - Main Controller Navigates In Views

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->view ();
    }
    public function view($page = 'home') {
        if (! file_exists ( "application/views/pages/$page.php" )) {
            show_404 ();
        }
        $data ['page'] = 'pages/' . $page;
        $this->load->view ( 'template/template.php', $data );
    }
}
```

## Members - Controller for managing membership system

```
class Members extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->model ( "members_model" );
    }
    public function login() {
        $this->members_model->login ();
    }
}
```

### My Routes Config

```
$route ['default_controller'] = "site";
$route ['(:any)'] = "site/view/$1";
```

So now I have a little problem which is when I call the members controller, it'll look for a page named members and not a controller named members.

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create other route for `Members`

```
$route ['members'] = "members";
$route ['members/(:any)'] = "members/$1";
$route ['default_controller'] = "site";
$route ['(:any)'] = "site/view/$1";
```

note that order is matter, the route above will use `members` first when matched route detected.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a specific route rule for that controller, like this one:

```
$route['members/(:any)'] = 'members/$1';
```

Or maybe add one for each method in your controller, like:

```
$route['members/login'] = 'members/login';
```

Note that you would need to add this/these rules to your `routes.php` file, but before any other rule that can match it. So you should got from the most specific to the most general rule.